# Bibliography LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have got a little problem with Bibliography in LaTeX. I'm using `report` style of document. When I use `\begin{thebibliography}` it will automatically add item to Table of Contents and type `\bibname` like a section in last chapter, not like a new chapter. I have to type `\bibname` like a single chapter and add the bibliography to the Table of Contents like a chapter, not like a section of last chapter. Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Within `\documentclass{report}`, the *default* for `thebibliography` environment is to issue `\chapter*{\bibname}`. Since you're reporting a different behaviour, other components may have an impact. What does your document preamble look like? What other bibliography-related packages are you using (like [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), perhaps)? In fact, it would be ideal if we could reproduce the problem by means of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to cope with your problem is to add the following incantation to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\thebibliography{\chapter*}{\chapter}{}{}
```

Just redefining `\refname` to do nothing will not solve the issue, as the `report` class uses `\bibname` and saying `\chapter{\bibname}` before `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` will produce *two* chapter pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\renewcommand*{\refname}{}` to clear the  heading definition of bibliography. Then simply use `\chapter{Bibliography}` before `thebibliography` environment. See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#As_numbered_item

```
\renewcommand*{\refname}{} % This will define heading of bibliography to be empty, so you can...
\chapter{Bibliography}     % ...place a normal chapter heading before the bibliography entries.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.